# How to have dateRangePicker effectively change state in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a daterange picker that I want to use to choose specific timestamps for users to query data essentially.

The example date Range Picker is below,

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';

import { formatDate, parseDate } from 'react-day-picker/moment';

export default class DateRange extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFromChange = this.handleFromChange.bind(this);
    this.handleToChange = this.handleToChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      from: undefined,
      to: undefined,
    };
  }

  showFromMonth() {
    const { from, to } = this.state;
    if (!from) {
      return;
    }
    if (moment(to).diff(moment(from), 'months') < 2) {
      this.to.getDayPicker().showMonth(from);
    }
  }

  handleFromChange(from) {
    // Change the from date and focus the "to" input field
    this.setState({ from });
  }

  handleToChange(to) {
    this.setState({ to }, this.showFromMonth);
  }

  render() {
    const { from, to } = this.state;
    const modifiers = { start: from, end: to };
    return (
      <div className="InputFromTo">
        <DayPickerInput
          value={from}
          placeholder="From"
          format="LL"
          formatDate={formatDate}
          parseDate={parseDate}
          dayPickerProps={{
            selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
            disabledDays: { after: to },
            toMonth: to,
            modifiers,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onDayClick: () => this.to.getInput().focus(),
          }}
          onDayChange={this.handleFromChange}
        />{' '}
        —{' '}
        <span className="InputFromTo-to">
          <DayPickerInput
            ref={el => (this.to = el)}
            value={to}
            placeholder="To"
            format="LL"
            formatDate={formatDate}
            parseDate={parseDate}
            dayPickerProps={{
              selectedDays: [from, { from, to }],
              disabledDays: { before: from },
              modifiers,
              month: from,
              fromMonth: from,
              numberOfMonths: 2,
            }}
            onDayChange={this.handleToChange}
          />
        </span>
        <Helmet>
          <style>{`
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--selected:not(.DayPicker-Day--start):not(.DayPicker-Day--end):not(.DayPicker-Day--outside) {
    background-color: #f0f8ff !important;
    color: #4a90e2;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--start {
    border-top-left-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPicker-Day--end {
    border-top-right-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% !important;
  }
  .InputFromTo .DayPickerInput-Overlay {
    width: 550px;
  }
  .InputFromTo-to .DayPickerInput-Overlay {
    margin-left: -198px;
  }
`}</style>
        </Helmet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This component is the child of this component,

```
import React from 'react';



import useAnalytics from './useAnalytics.js'
export default function Analytics() {
  const {magicData,
  ...
  } = useAnalytics();
  return (
    <div className="relative">
     ...
      <DateRange />
      ...
          <LineGraphs sentimentData={sentimentData} />
      
       ....
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then the data is being produce with a separate file into this one,  i.e.,

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useMemo, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { apiRequest } from '../../../util/util';
import { format } from "date-fns";
import groupBy from "lodash/groupBy";
// import get from "lodash/get";

....


export default function useAnalytics() {
  var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);

  const [EndDate, setEndDate] = useState((Date.now()));
  const [StartDate, setStartDate] = useState(d.getTime());

....
const { data: magicData } = useSWR(
  `xxx/xxx/xx-xx-xxx?startTime=${StartDate}&endTime=${EndDate}`,
  apiRequest
);




  return {
    magicData,
  };
}
```

I want the Day Range picker to be set the start and end date, and then to change the query to the database or alternatively filter the existing data in cache for users in their graphs (so can avoid calling lots of data for no reason).

I'm really confused how to have the state in the useAnalytics page be linked to the DateRange component - I would like to be able to just change the state of useAnalytics with the DateRange component.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: What does happen with `useSWR` ?

Comment: it's a next.js library for fetching with ssr and client side